# Radon-Nikodym derivative for discrete measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Could you, please, check the following:

Let's consider a real line $\mathbb{R}$ and let's define two measures on it. For some (possibly finite) sequences $s_{1}, s_{2}, \dots$ and $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots$, s.t. $a_{i}>0$ and $\sum_{i}a_{i} = 1$, let
$$
\begin{equation}
  \delta_{s_i}(X)=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $s_{i}\in X$}\\
    0, & \text{if $s_{i}\not\in X$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
for any  Lebesgue measurable set $X$. Next, we define 
$$
\nu = \sum_{i}a_{i}\delta_{s_i},
$$
and
$$
\mu = \sum_{i}\delta_{s_i}.
$$

Then, one can see that $\nu$ is a discrete probability distribution on $s_{1}, s_{2}, \dots$.

**Statement**: $\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt to $\mu$, also for any measurable set $A$
$$
\nu(A) = \int_{A} f d\mu,
$$
where $f$ is Radon-Nikodym derivative and
$$
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    a_{i}, & \text{if $x=s_{i}$, for some $i$}\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: $f(s_i)$ should be $a_i$.

Comment: Dear @Zeros, thank you, I have fixed it.